# Jupyter's slides doesnt fit on my screen?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, rise

I'm using Rise to create a slideshow of my notebook, but I'm having this issue:

[image: When I'm writing my code, everything is fine.]

But, when I click "Enter RISE Slideshow"...

[image: It looks like this]

Couldnt find anyone with the same issue. Someone know what to do?
Also, is there an aquivalent of this metod in Jupyter Lab?

Comment: You can increase or decrease size from google page size

Comment: If you're talking about the zoom, it doesnt work...still looking the same.